# revert option is not working

Tags: parachain, rococo, parachain-collator

We are facing a returning "Too many sibling blocks inserted" error then all 4 collator nodes would stop block production. I did some research into the issue and one of the possible solution was to use the revert option. However when I try to run the command it returns a bunch of errors:

```
/usr/local/bin/collator revert -d /datalocation --log trace --detailed-log-output --chain=/datalocation/xxx-rococo-raw.json 1

2023-01-30 08:09:45.161 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.
2023-01-30 08:09:45.162 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task `transaction-pool-task-0` failed. Shutting down service.
2023-01-30 08:09:45.162 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task `transaction-pool-task-1` failed. Shutting down service.
2023-01-30 08:09:45.162 DEBUG tokio-runtime-worker block-import: Stopping block import because result channel was closed!
2023-01-30 08:09:45.162 ERROR tokio-runtime-worker sc_service::task_manager: Essential task `basic-block-import-worker` failed. Shutting down service.
2023-01-30 08:09:45.255 TRACE tokio-runtime-worker mio::poll: deregistering event source from poller
```

What am I missing? We are using version v0.9.37.

Comment: Please, add the versions you are using to your post.

Comment: check this issue: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/10583

Comment: That doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. I should have an output confirming that 1 block has been reverted which is not happening right now. Any other ideas?